# How to render Markdown headings in SwiftUI AttributedString?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, markdown, attributedstring

I've been trying to use the new [AttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/attributedstring) that released with iOS 15 to render Markdown stored in a variable. However, I haven't been able to find a way for it to render markdown headings such as:

```
# Title 1
### Title 3
###### Title 6
```

Here's my code:

```swift
let description = """
        # Hello World

        Coin coin
        """
let attributed = (try? AttributedString(markdown: description)) ?? AttributedString(description)
return ScrollView {
    Text(attributed)
        .padding(.horizontal)
}
```

But here's what's displayed in the preview:

[image]

Does anyone successfully got them working or is this something impossible to do as of now?

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-render-markdown-content-in-text

Comment: Yes, I saw that article, but he doesn't try headings either because he didn't think about it, or because he came across the same problem.

Comment: It just mean it is not supported.

Comment: Same issue here. Found this: ```The current version of Swift doesn’t support all the Markdown syntax. For example, it can’t render heading, numbered list, and image. Hopefully, Apple will provide further improvement in future updates of SwiftUI.```

Comment: Still not rendering headings in iOS 16

Comment: the same in iOS 17 Beta, no rendering for headings

Answer (score 19):

The markdown is parsed properly, the problem seems to be that nothing is done with the presentation intents for headers.

You could look through the presentation intents and apply the styling manually to headers.

You'll have to use `interpretedSyntax: .full` which will mean that whitespace is ignored, so you might want to also add a new line after each block.

```
extension AttributedString {
    init(styledMarkdown markdownString: String) throws {
        var output = try AttributedString(
            markdown: markdownString,
            options: .init(
                allowsExtendedAttributes: true,
                interpretedSyntax: .full,
                failurePolicy: .returnPartiallyParsedIfPossible
            ),
            baseURL: nil
        )

        for (intentBlock, intentRange) in output.runs[AttributeScopes.FoundationAttributes.PresentationIntentAttribute.self].reversed() {
            guard let intentBlock = intentBlock else { continue }
            for intent in intentBlock.components {
                switch intent.kind {
                case .header(level: let level):
                    switch level {
                    case 1:
                        output[intentRange].font = .system(.title).bold()
                    case 2:
                        output[intentRange].font = .system(.title2).bold()
                    case 3:
                        output[intentRange].font = .system(.title3).bold()
                    default:
                        break
                    }
                default:
                    break
                }
            }
            
            if intentRange.lowerBound != output.startIndex {
                output.characters.insert(contentsOf: "\n", at: intentRange.lowerBound)
            }
        }

        self = output
    }
}
```

[image: Example]

As far as I can see only `baselineOffset`, `backgroundColor`, `font`, `foregroundColor`, `kern`, `strikethroughStyle`, `tracking`, and `underlineStyle` are supported in SwiftUI.

It's not a perfect solution, but it might get you closer to what you need.