# Is it possible to import Markdown text file to SwiftUI and display the text in a view?

Tags: swiftui, markdown

I was wondering if it is possible to import markdown files into your SwiftUI project (in Xcode) and then display the contents of the file inside of an SwiftUI view? It would be pretty neat if one have a lot of text to process and just import it by a simple method?

I've tried using:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ShowMarkdown: View {
    // Get the path to your markdown file.
    let filepath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "filename", withExtension: "md")
    
    var body: some View {
        // Show the markdown.
        Text(try! AttributedString(contentsOf: filepath!))
    }
}
```

The problem with using above code is that for one thing it doesn't display the headers correctly. I want it to look like what you see in a preview of an simple Markdown file.

Comment: can you show us an example file you want to display but does not display well.

Comment: I Use the code you see down below with the following markdown code (just to test out): 
#Title

##Title2
BLA BLA and BLA

##Title3

###Title4

Comment: try using your code with, `*Title* **Title2** BLA BLA and BLA **Title3** **Title4**`, note the `*` not the `#`. Works for me.

Comment: Note, headings are not supported according to this post: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70643384/how-to-render-markdown-headings-in-swiftui-attributedstring  In other words, your code works but the headings will not be shown as desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Text` views can display Markdown directly, but rather than initialise with a `String` variable, you'll need to use `LocalizedStringKey`…

```
struct ShowMarkdown: View {
    // Get the path to your markdown file.
    
    var text: LocalizedStringKey {
        let filepath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "filename", withExtension: "md")!
         return LocalizedStringKey(try! String(contentsOf: filepath))
    }


    var body: some View {
        // Show the markdown.
        Text(text)
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately my program crash when using above code. I tried creating a simple view with only the above code and a new markdown file and it crashes...

Comment: What crash are you seeing? Does the filename.md exist in your bundle?

Comment: It says "implicity unwrapped nil value in ShowMarkdown..."

And the filename.md is in the same folder as the swiftUI file.

Is there something silly that I'm forgetting or not seeing?

Comment: Make sure the filename.md is added to your target